# Como armazenar uma List<object> em um banco de dados?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, lista

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em C# onde tenho a seguinte situação.

Tenho uma classe que representa jogador:

```
class Player
{
   int ID;
   string Name;
}
```

e outra que representa um time:

```
class Team
{
   int ID, 
   string Name;
   List<Player> PlayersInThisTeam;
}
```

O problema é que não tenho conhecimento sobre bancos de dados e não conheço o jeito correto de armazenar uma Lista.

Comment: Vou prepara um exemplo pra você, assim que concluir posto aqui

Comment: Achei a pergunta um pouco ampla, porque podem surgir respostas com "n" formas diferentes, usando "n" frameworks diferentes, etc.. e nem sempre a resposta terá tudo que você precisa. Seria mais interessante ter informações mais específicas, como o ORM e banco de dados utilizado, o que você já fez, se está dando algum erro, etc... mas é só uma sugestão de melhoria ok

Comment: Ele não tem um *framework* específico. A ideia da pergunta é justamente ter por onde começar. É ampla, mas não no nível que justifique um fechamento.

Comment: Realmente ficou meio vago minha pergunta. Eu estou usando o Xamarin.Forms para criar um app mobile, e pretendo armazenar os dados num banco de dados SQL do Microsoft Azure

Answer (score 12):

Primeiro você precisa escolher um banco de dados para trabalhar. Para C# há várias opções, sendo o [Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=42299) a opção mais completa para trabalhar com C#.

Para persistir seus dados, o recomendado é usar um ORM (*Object Relational Mapper*, mapeador objeto relacional). Também há várias opções, sendo a mais completa o [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/), que cria e modifica o banco pra você de acordo com o seu código, faz carga preguiçosa e antecipada de dados agregados, cuida de algumas validações e mais alguns recursos.

No Entity Framework, seu `Player` fica assim:

```
public class Player
{
   [Key]
   public int PlayerId { get; set; }
   public int? TeamId { get; set; } // O jogador pode ou não ter um time

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

E seu `Team`:

```
public class Team
{
   [Key]
   public int TeamId { get; set; } 
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Player> PlayersInThisTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Inserindo um time:

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
context.Teams.Add(new Team {
    Name = "Time"
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Inserindo um jogador:

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
context.Players.Add(new Player {
    Name = "Jogador"
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Atualizando um jogador:

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
var player = context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Jogador");
if (player != null) 
{
    player.Name = "Fulano";
    context.Entry(player).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Excluindo um jogador

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
var player = context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Jogador");
if (player != null) 
{
    context.Players.Remove(player);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Selecionando todos os jogadores:

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
var allPlayers = context.Players.ToList();
```

Associando um time a um jogador

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
var player = context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Fulano");
if (player != null)
{
    var timeJogador = context.Teams.FirstOfDefault(t => t.Name == "Time");
    if (timeJogador != null)
    {
        player.Time = timeJogador;
        context.Entry(player).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Selecionando um time e todos os seus jogadores (carga antecipada)

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
var timeComJogadores = context.Teams
                              .Include(t => t.PlayersInThisTeam)
                              .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Time");
// timeJogadores.PlayersInThisTeam virá com os jogadores populados.
```

Selecionando um time e todos os seus jogadores (carga preguiçosa)

```
public SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();
var timeComJogadores = context.Teams
                              .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Time");
var jogadores = timeComJogadores.PlayersInThisTeam.ToList(); // Aqui forço uma segunda consulta apenas com os jogadores.
```

Answer (score 9):

Complementando ao Cigano, você pode usar o Dapper ​*com o EF*​ ou com uma conexão que implemente ISqlConnection

> O Dapper trabalha com extension methods para a sua conexão, ou seja,
>   você irá inicialmente criar uma conexão para o seu banco de dados,
>   como se fosse utilizar ADO.Net, por exemplo: SqlConnection,
>   OracleConnection, MySqlConnection, etc. No caso do Dapper, você também
>   é o responsável por abrir e fechar a sua conexão.

Classe Player

```
 public class Player
{

    [Key] //DataAnnotations - referenciando chave primária
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Fks
    [ForeignKey("Team")]  //DataAnnotations - referenciando FK
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }  // propriedade navegativa 
}
```

Classe Team

```
public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Fks
        public ICollection<Player> Player { get; set; }
    }
```

Código

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Inserindo Team
            Console.WriteLine("DIgite o nome do Team");
            string nomeTeam = Console.ReadLine();
            var conexao = new TeamPlayerContext().Database.Connection;
            conexao.Query("INSERT INTO Teams (Name) values(@Name)", new { Name = nomeTeam }); // Salvando team

            // Inserindo Player e vinculando a team
            Console.WriteLine("DIgite o nome do jogador");
            string nomeJogador= Console.ReadLine();
                        conexao.Open();
                var dados = conexao.Query("select * from Teams");
                foreach (dynamic linha in dados)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", linha.TeamId, linha.Name);
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Digite para qual time o jogador joga");
            int timeJogador = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            conexao.Query("INSERT INTO  Players(Name, TeamId) values(@Name, @TeamId)", new { Name = nomeJogador, TeamID = timeJogador }); // salvando player
            // Limpando a tela
            Console.Clear();
            // listando jogadores cadatrados
            Console.WriteLine("Jogadores Cadastrados");
            var jogadores = conexao.Query("select * from Players");
            foreach (dynamic linha in dados)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} -- {2}", linha.PlayerId, linha.Name, linha.TeamId);
            }
            // Listando team Cadastrados
            Console.WriteLine("Times Cadastrados");
            var times = conexao.Query("select * from Teams");
            foreach (dynamic linha in dados)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", linha.TeamId, linha.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            conexao.Close();
        }
```

Comment: na sua introdução você não quis dizer "você pode usar o Dapper com**o** o EF"?

Comment: Sim, já ajustei @TobyMosque