# Realizar insert into em List do c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, lista, sql-insert

Alguém poderia dar um exemplo de como seria um insert de sql em uma lista em c#?

Comment: Pode ser um exemplo com EntityFramewokr?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como armazenar uma List<object> em um banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142964/como-armazenar-uma-listobject-em-um-banco-de-dados)

Answer (score 3):

[Como armazenar uma List<object> em um banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142964/como-armazenar-uma-listobject-em-um-banco-de-dados)

nessa pergunta você pode ver alguns exemplos de como fazer insert com c#, na resposta do Cigano é usado somente `EnityFramework`.
Na resposta do Lucas, ele utiliza `Dapper` e `EntityFramework`

Mas para fazer insert usado somente comandos SQL, você tem que usar o `SqlConnection` e `SqlCommand` ,
ficando algo do tipo.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Banco;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id],[Name]) VALUES (@Id, @Name)", conn);

    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.NewGuid();
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256).Value = "Nome";

    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        tb_User tb = new  tb_User ();
        tb.Nome="Manuel";
        tb.Idade=30;

        DB.DB.AddTotb_User(tb);
        DB.DB.Connection.Open();
        DB.DB.SaveChanges();
        DB.DB.Connection.Close();
```

Entity Framework.