# Como salvar dados no banco SQL - Submit

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou estudando ASP.NET MVC, estou utilizando o `Identity` para realizar o controle de usuários e etc.

Então, criei uma pagina, aonde o usuário ira entrar com 4 informações:

1. Quilometragem Inicial;
2. Quilometragem Final;
3. Quantidade de litros abastecidos;
4. Valor em R$.

Então criei um `Model` chamado `CombustivelModel`:

```
namespace OneeWeb_v2.Models
{
    public class CombustivelModels
    {
        public string km_inicial { get; set; }
        public string km_final { get; set; }
        public string litros { get; set; }
        public string valor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Então criei um `Controller` chamado `CombustivelController`:

```
namespace OneeWeb_v2.Controllers
{
    public class CombustivelController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Combustivel
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

E criei a sua `View` :

```
@model OneeWeb_v2.Models.CombustivelModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Controle de combustivel</h2>

<dt>Abastecimento</dt>

<div>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.km_inicial, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "KM Inicial" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.km_final, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "KM Final" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.litros, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Litros" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.valor, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Valor R$" })

</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default submit" />
</div>
```

Porém, como faço para salvar as informações no banco de dados?

Estou utilizando SQL Server, ja configurei a `ConnectionString` no `WebConfig`

Conforme solicitação, segue o `IdentityModels`:

```
    namespace OneeWeb_v2.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está utilizando o Entity framework? Se sim, está já configurou o **DbContext**?

Comment: Sim estou usando, e a configuração DBcontext é no `IdentityModels`? se sim já!

Comment: Poste também o `IdentityModels`

Comment: conforme solicitado, edição feita.

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel Você nunca usou EntityFramework?

Comment: Não, estou me aventurando agora.. rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou definir uma chave primária no seu *Model*, e mais algumas coisas. Altere para o seguinte:

```
public class Combustivel
{
    [Key]
    public int CombustivelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal km_inicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal km_final { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal litros { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
}
```

Por [*Scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a2999%20scaffolding), podemos usar os seguintes clichês sugeridos pela Microsoft para criação, edição e exclusão:

```
public class CombustiveisController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Combustiveis
    public async Task<ActionResult> Indice()
    {
        return View(await db.Combustiveis.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Combustiveis/Detalhes/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Detalhes(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Combustivel combustivel = await db.Combustiveis.FindAsync(id);
        if (combustivel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(combustivel);
    }

    // GET: Combustiveis/Criar
    public ActionResult Criar()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Combustiveis/Criar
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Criar([Bind(Include = "CombustivelId,km_inicial,km_final,litros,valor")] Combustivel combustivel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Combustiveis.Add(combustivel);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Indice");
        }

        return View(combustivel);
    }

    // GET: Combustiveis/Editar/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Editar(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Combustivel combustivel = await db.Combustiveis.FindAsync(id);
        if (combustivel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(combustivel);
    }

    // POST: Combustiveis/Editar/{id}
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Editar([Bind(Include = "CombustivelId,km_inicial,km_final,litros,valor")] Combustivel combustivel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(combustivel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Indice");
        }
        return View(combustivel);
    }

    // GET: Combustiveis/Excluir/{id}
    public async Task<ActionResult> Excluir(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Combustivel combustivel = await db.Combustiveis.FindAsync(id);
        if (combustivel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(combustivel);
    }

    // POST: Combustiveis/Excluir/{id}
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Excluir")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmarExclusao(int id)
    {
        Combustivel combustivel = await db.Combustivels.FindAsync(id);
        db.Combustivels.Remove(combustivel);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Indice");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Aqui estou considerando que você está usando Entity Framework com Microsoft SQL Server, como sua pergunta diz.

[A resposta do @Randrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168554/2999) faz o mapeamento do `DbSet` manualmente. O procedimento de *Scaffolding* adiciona o `DbSet` automaticamente pra você ao contexto.

`DbSet`? Contexto? Dúvidas sobre como usar? [Veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142964/como-armazenar-uma-listobject-em-um-banco-de-dados/142973#142973).

As *Views* também são clichês:

## `Create.cshtml`

```
@model OneeWeb_v2.Models.Combustivel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Combustivel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.km_inicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.km_inicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.km_inicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.km_final, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.km_final, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.km_final, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.litros, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.litros, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.litros, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para Listagem", "Indice")
</div>
```

## `Edit.cshtml`

```
@model OneeWeb_v2.Models.Combustivel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Combustivel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CombustivelId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.km_inicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.km_inicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.km_inicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.km_final, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.km_final, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.km_final, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.litros, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.litros, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.litros, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para Listagem", "Indice")
</div>
```

## `Delete.cshtml`

```
@model OneeWeb_v2.Models.Combustivel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Você tem certeza de que deseja excluir este registro?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Combustivel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.km_inicial)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.km_inicial)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.km_final)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.km_final)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.litros)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.litros)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.valor)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.valor)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Excluir" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para Listagem", "Indice")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

## `Details.cshtml`

```
@model OneeWeb_v2.Models.Combustivel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Combustivel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.km_inicial)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.km_inicial)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.km_final)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.km_final)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.litros)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.litros)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.valor)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.valor)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Editar", new { id = Model.CombustivelId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para Listagem", "Indice")
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro passo, atualize o seu `IdentityModels` para mapear o seu modelo, desta forma:

```
namespace OneeWeb_v2.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        //Aqui que está a alteração
        public DbSet<CombustivelModels> Combustiveis { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Após isso, vamos "normalizar" o seu controller. Para isso, vamos criar um método **POST** para salvar os dados digitados, desta forma:

```
namespace OneeWeb_v2.Controllers
{
    public class CombustivelController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: /Combustivel
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CombustivelModels model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Combustiveis.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

E, adicionamos o `Html.BeginForm()` na View para "ela saber" o que fazer com os dados, desta forma:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.km_inicial, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "KM Inicial" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.km_final, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "KM Final" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.litros, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Litros" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.valor, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Valor R$" })

    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default submit" />
    </div>
}
```

Agora, isso tudo pode ser gerado automaticamente por **scaffolding**. [Esta resposta mostra detalhadamente como fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32749/20615).

> A sugestão é que suas Actions possuam o nome do que irá fazer, por exemplo, Criar para criar algo, etc. Adicionei a Action **POST** com o nome de Index apenas para ficar mais fácil o entendimento.